# Launchd execute command when folder contents modified or changed

Tags: mac, unix, launchd

For the past two days i've been trying to **get a launchd plist to execute a script** "program" **when the contents of a folder on my desktop contents have modified or changed**. I've gone through tons of configuration settings and have tried the `Users/me/Desktop/folderinquestion` and `Users/me/Desktop/folderinquestion` (with and without trailing slash).

The script executes only when something is added or removed but it **doesn't recognize when files are updated and subdirectories**. launchd is really my last hope to getting this to working i've already exausted folder actions, and bash scripts, uninstallable linux methods etc.

I have used [Lingon](http://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/) to create my plists and have followed [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1diirrvJR6I) youtube tutorial. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is what I have right now, and like I said does not work when folder is modified or changed

[image]

IDEA:

Thinking about creating two separate plists that reference each other one plist can watch a folder for additions and subtractions and when one occurs it can create another plist that watches every file in the folder, this could also be recursive and count in for subdirectories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `launchd` supports that level of monitoring; you can watch individual files or you can watch for additions to a directory, but you can't do full `inotify`/`fam`/`gamin`-style watching of an entire directory tree.  You would need to run as a standalone daemon and use either BSD `kqueue` or Mach ports (or use `fam` or `gamin` to do it for you) to monitor your tree.

Comment: Since this is OS X, [FSEvents](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) seems line the obvious tool for this.  Peter Hosey posted [some sample code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913401/fsevents-weirdness-on-os-x-leopard) over on stackoverflow.