# run script on directory modification

Tags: macos, mac, filesystems

For `launchd` there is `WatchPaths` (and for some more specific case `QueueDirectories`) which monitors changes on a path. However, if it is a directory, it will only recognize creations/deletions in the directory, i.e. not changed content of the containing files or any changes in any subdirectories (see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/302240/launchd-execute-command-when-folder-contents-modified-or-changed)).

(For Linux, some good solutions seem to be listed [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/50127/how-to-automatically-run-a-script-when-the-contents-of-a-directory-changes-in-li).)

It seems like `launchd` is not able to do it, is it?

I could write my own always-running daemon which extends `launchd` by this functionality, via FSEvents (or kqueue, [fam](http://oss.sgi.com/projects/fam/) or [gamin](https://people.gnome.org/~veillard/gamin/)?).

Or are there existing projects/tools which can do that?

Answer (score 0):

`launchd` should also monitor for changes to files (directly) under directories in `WatchPaths`.

Try saving this plist as `~/Library/LaunchAgents/test.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>test</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>say</string>
    <string>a</string>
  </array>
  <key>WatchPaths</key>
  <array>
    <string>~/Documents/</string>
  </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Then run `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/test.plist` and modify some file under `~/Documents/`. The program should be run even if you modify the file without performing an atomic save or even if the modification time of `~/Documents/` is not changed.

Note that `launchd` does not monitor for changes in subdirectories of the watched directories. Tilde expansion works in the arguments for `WatchPaths` by default, but there is no way to enable filename expansion. (`EnableGlobbing` only applies to `ProgramArguments`.)

Comment: According to my link, it does not. But even if it does, it is still not useful for me because I want a solution which monitors all of the content, i.e. also subdirectories.